# maskRe ExtJS 6.0.2

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs, extjs6

I'm simply trying to limit the user to input a number between 1 and 6. So my codes is:

```
{
        xtype            : 'textfield',
        id               : 'NUMBER',
        width            : '100%',
        fieldLabel       : "NUMBER",
        dataIndex        : 'NUMBER',
        maxLength        : 1,
        value            : 0,
        regex            : /[0-6\/]/,
        maskRe           : /[0-6]/,
        enforceMaxLength : true,
        readOnly         : true,
        mandatory        : true,
}
```

For some reason i can input any number from 1 to 9 (although i get the invalid form error). Also, since the starting value is 0 for some reason i can add a number before him, allowing me for example to input "90".

So my final question is, "Why doesn't my "maskRe" works properly"?

Comment: why don 't you use min max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, sans the `readOnly:true`, is working in a fiddle for me; so I am not sure why it doesn't work for you.

[You can find the fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2634); note that I tested in most recent Chrome only.

Comment: You're right the fiddle is correct, sorry but i had another function on the controller which was ignoring my field properties. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for:

```
{
  xtype: 'numberfield',
  label: 'Age',
  minValue: 1,
  maxValue: 6,
  name: 'age'
}
```

Regarding `maskRe`, they say:

> maskRe : RegExp 
>   An input mask regular expression that will be used to filter keystrokes >
>   (character being typed) that do not match. Note: It does not filter characters > already in the input.

so a maskRe of /[1-6]/ will just let user enter 1 to 6 chars but will not invalidate the 0 already in and will not impose a length restriction.

Comment: To tell you the true, i was avoiding the use of the "numberfield" since I'm using it to have a special behavior. But even if i use that, for some reason i can still input 7, 8 and 9.

Comment: Describe the special behavior and maybe I can help you accomplish it :) Also you can have a sneak peek in the Number field class sources to see how they enforce the restrictions ;)

Comment: i have 2 "arrows" ("up" and "down") which allow me to increment/decrement the numeric value. Those arrows only allow me to increase the number till 6, but once again i can still edit it to be 7.

Comment: [You can input 7, 8, 9, 10, but this will invalidate the field,](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2633),  and thus, the form. You have to check that the form is valid before allowing submission.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, but i just wanted to restrict the user to 1-6 values. And for my understanding the maskRe would solve this problem perfectly.